# De-Serializing msg_container objects returned from the telegram.org server

Tags: python, api, telegram

I'm having trouble de-serializing a `msg_container` object. The issue seems to be my understanding of where the `flags` field is located in the `message` as it doesn't make sense to me. My assumptions below come from reading this page: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL

Here is what I am seeing, I'm hoping someone can clarify.

A response from the telegram server looks like this:

```
    ('server_answer: ', '\xdc\xf8\xf1s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x018\xcb\x8cCu\xcdW\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x08\t\xc2\x9e\x00t\xbe?Cu\xcdW\x82\x0e:\x11\xe0\xda\xed\x05\xd7\xbezI4\x05Tf\x01\xdc\xcb\x8cCu\xcdW\x02\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00Y\xb4\xd6b\x15\xc4\xb5\x1c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00t\xbe?Cu\xcdW')

 0 | DC F8 F1 73 02 00 00 00
 8 | 01 38 CB 8C 43 75 CD 57
16 | 01 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00
24 | 08 09 C2 9E 00 74 BE 3F
32 | 43 75 CD 57 82 0E 3A 11
40 | E0 DA ED 05 D7 BE 7A 49
48 | 34 05 54 66 01 DC CB 8C
56 | 43 75 CD 57 02 00 00 00
64 | 14 00 00 00 59 B4 D6 62
72 | 15 C4 B5 1C 01 00 00 00
80 | 00 74 BE 3F 43 75 CD 57
```

Which indicates a `MessageContainer` object, which looks like this:

```
msg_container#73f1f8dc messages:vector<message> = MessageContainer;
```

(Note: 73f1f8dc is the first four bytes returned, in little-endian order)

Since a `msg_container` is a `vector` of `messages` the next integer is the `message` count, which is `00 00 00 02`, so there are two messages in this vector.

A `message` looks like this:

```
message#c09be45f flags:# out:flags.1?true mentioned:flags.4?true media_unread:flags.5?true silent:flags.13?true post:flags.14?true id:int from_id:flags.8?int to_id:Peer fwd_from:flags.2?MessageFwdHeader via_bot_id:flags.11?int reply_to_msg_id:flags.3?int date:int message:string media:flags.9?MessageMedia reply_markup:flags.6?ReplyMarkup entities:flags.7?Vector<MessageEntity> views:flags.10?int edit_date:flags.15?int = Message;
messageService#9e19a1f6 flags:# out:flags.1?true mentioned:flags.4?true media_unread:flags.5?true silent:flags.13?true post:flags.14?true id:int from_id:flags.8?int to_id:Peer reply_to_msg_id:flags.3?int date:int action:MessageAction = Message;
```

So I am assuming the next four bytes will be the first parameter in the first message, which is the `flags` field. But the value of that four bytes is `8c cb 38 01` which is 2362128385L as an unsigned integer, which is suspiciously large for a simple bit mask. Plus, if I use this value to de-serialize the optional parameters from the rest of the byte stream they don't make sense and eventually fail with a type mismatch. I've tried the `flags` field as a signed integer as well with similar results.

What is incorrect about my understanding of how the telegram server responds with msg_container objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to use in handling messages packed in a container:

```
Container_type_header
Content_count
[messages]
```

Each message is packed like so:

```
msgs_id
seq_no
mgs_len
msg_body
```

given your sample data:

```
DCF8F173 --> container_type_header
02000000 --> message_count_in_container

0138CB8C4375CD57 --> msg_id of first message
01000000 --> seq_no of first message
1C000000 --> length of first message; 1C == 28 bytes
0809C29E0074BE3F4375CD57820E3A11E0DAED05D7BE7A4934055466 --> 28 byte msg_body

01DCCB8C4375CD57 --> msg_id of second message
02000000 --> seq_number of second message
14000000 --> lenght of second message; 14 == 20 bytes
59B4D66215C4B51C010000000074BE3F4375CD57 --> 20 byte msg_body
```

when decoded first message gives:

```
0809C29E0074BE3F4375CD57820E3A11E0DAED05D7BE7A4934055466

New_Session_Created{first_msg_id: 6326841983218119680,  server_salt: 7373524212041563863, unique_id: 427238195566612098}
```

when decoded second message gives:

```
0x59B4D66215C4B51C010000000074BE3F4375CD57 

Msgs_Ack{msg_ids: [6326841983218119680]}
```

Comment: Wow, I never would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? It seems inconsistent with the way the rest of the data types work since I can't find a data type that consists of: msg_id, seq_number, length, msg_body.

Comment: you need to read the API documentation pages and some trial and error :)